# Relation between enveloping algebras and algebras of differential operators

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, differential-operators

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759223/map-of-the-enveloping-algebra-to-the-ring-of-differential-operators) on math stack exchange about 3 years ago, but received no answer.

Our base field $\mathsf{k}$ will be algebraically closed of zero characteristic. Let $X$ be an smooth affine variety, $\mathcal{V}_X$ the Lie algebra of vector fields on $X$ and $A_X$ the algebra o regular functions in $X$. It is known that $\mathcal{V}_X$ is an infinite dimensional simple Lie algebra.

$\mathcal{V}_X$ appears as a Lie subalgebra of $\mathcal{D}(X)^{(-)}$, where $\mathcal{D}(X)$ is the algebra of differential operators in $X$. Hence we have a map $\phi: U(\mathcal{V}_X) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}(X)$.

My question is: what can we say about $\operatorname{ker} \phi$ and $\operatorname{Im} \phi$?

EDIT: as Joshua Mundinger explained in the comments, $\phi$ is surjective.

**Background I - Representation Theory**:

I first became interested in this question when I learned about the theory of $A\mathcal{V}$-modules introduced by Billig, Futorny and Nilsson.

In general, it is a hopeless task to classify all irreducible $\mathcal{V}_X$ representations. Hence it is reasonable to focus attention on a suitable subcategory of modules: $A \mathcal{V}$-modules

*Definition*: With $X$, $\mathcal{V}_X$ and $A_X$ as above, $M$ is called an $A\mathcal{V}$-module if it is a module for the Lie algebra $\mathcal{V}_X$, a module for the commutative algebra $A_X$, and the actions are related by $ \nu(fm)=f(\nu m) + \nu(f)m$, $\nu \in \mathcal{V}_X, f \in A_X, m \in M$.

Clearly, every $\mathcal{D}(X)$-module is an $A\mathcal{V}$-module, but not conversely: consider the adjoint representation of $\mathcal{V}_X$, for example.

So, in a sense, this class of modules is 'between' the full category of $U(\mathcal{V}_X)$-modules and the category of $\mathcal{D}(X)$-modules. Being more precise, $A \mathcal{V}$-modules corresponde to modules for the smash product algebra $A_X * U(\mathcal{V}_X)$ (and hence the category of $A\mathcal{V}$-modules is an abelian category).

**Background II - Ring Theory**

I am also interested in this question because of its ring theoretic side. The algebras $U(\mathcal{V}_X)$ and $\mathcal{D}(X)$ are quite different. $\mathcal{D}(X)$ is a left and right Noetherian simple algebra. $U(\mathcal{V}_X)$ is never simple, and conjecturally never Noetherian (this was confirmed in case $X=\mathbb{A}^1$ or $\mathbb{T}^1$, by Sierra and Walton). So the kernel of the map $\phi$ I considered should be very big.

A result somewhat related to my question, recently obtained by Billig, Ingalls and Nasr, is that if $X$ is the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$, calling the Lie algebra of vector fields by $\mathcal{W}$, we have $\mathsf{k}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]*U(\mathcal{W}) \simeq A_n(\mathsf{k}) \otimes U(\mathcal{W}+)$ , where $A_n(\mathsf{k})$ is the Weyl algebra and $\mathcal{W}+$ is the subalgebra of $\mathcal{W}$ consisting of vector fields that vanish at the origin.

Comment: The map $\phi$ is surjective. Work locally on $X$: if $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ are étale coordinates and $\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n$ are the corresponding partial derivatives, then $\mathcal D(X)$ is a free $\mathcal O_X$-module with basis $\partial_1^{i_1}\cdots \partial_n^{i_n}$, and $f \partial_1^{i_1} \cdots \partial_n^{i_n} = \phi( (f \partial_1)(\partial_1)\cdots (\partial_n))$.

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, the kernel will be infinite dimensional (at least for $\dim X \geq 1$).  To see this, you can take the order filtration on $\mathcal D(X)$ and the PBW filtration on $U(\mathcal V_X)$.  The map $U(\mathcal V_X) \to \mathcal D(X)$ is compatible with the filtration, and on the $k$th associated graded we get the map $${\rm Sym}^k T_X \to {\rm Sym}_{A_X}^k ~T _X.$$  Here the first symmetric power is over the base field and the second is taken with respect to $A_X$.   This map is surjective with an infinite dimensional kernel when $k \geq 2$, therefore the same will hold before taking associated gradeds.

**Ex:**   If $x$ is a local parameter then $[x \partial_x] [x^{i} \partial_x] - [\partial_x][ x^{i+1} \partial_x]$ is an element of ${\rm Sym}^2 T_X$ which becomes zero in ${\rm Sym}^2_{A_X} T_X$.  This corresponds to the element of the kernel of $\phi$ given by $$x \partial_x \cdot x^{i} \partial_x - \partial_x\cdot  x^{i+1} \partial_x +  x^i \partial_x.$$  This gives an infinite dimensional space of elements in the kernel.

Comment: By $T_X$ you mean the Lie algebra of derivations?

Comment: @jg1896 Yes $T_X = \mathcal V_X$ is the tangent module of $A_X$.